# use selector to call function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why does the following code not work?

```
[Confirm addTarget:self 
            action:@selector([FunctionsApp Synch_Data:CompIDS]) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

given:

> FunctionsApp: its other class
>
> Synch_Data:its function in FunctionsApp
>
> CompIDS: its MSmutableArray

Comment: error:methode name missing in @selector  and expecting:before token[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FunctionsApp *functions = [[FunctionsApp alloc] init];//of course u need to use your own init method
[Confirm addTarget:functions action:@selector(Synch_Data) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

the selector u pass is just the name of the method this is passed to the target who in turn checks if it exists and then calls it. u cant use a mutable array as a selector. since `confirm` is a button u should use a method with signature `- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender` where sender will be the button. and also since the selector is not a class-method you do not call it like this `[FunctionsApp buttonClicked:]` but instead you use the FunctionsApp object reference as target ( i.e. where the method exists as target).
and please elaborate your question next time and be a bit more concrete in what things are.

Comment: u can then inside the buttonClicked: method access and do what u want to the CompIDS array. and you should also read some kind of beginners guide on naming conventions and stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this one thing at a time.

**1.**
`-[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]` has specific requirements to what the `action` selector can look like.

It can be one of the following:

```
- (void)action;
- (void)action:(id)sender;
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Normally you'd use the second one.

**2.**
`@selector` takes the name of the method (selector) you'd like to have called on the target. You're specifying the return value of a method call. That's the error, you're seeing.

So to call `Sync_Data:` (which in objective-c would be `syncData:`) on `FunctionsApp` you'd write

```
[Confirm addTarget:FunctionsApp action:@selector(Synch_Data:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You still can't pass the `CompIDS` variable as a parameter, though, so I'd suggest rewriting your code, to make it an instance variable, that your action method can access.

Comment: it mean i can't pass CompIDS??

Comment: @cs1.6 That's right. The variable passed in the `action` method is the sender, which would be the `UIControl` that triggered the message.